# AWS S3 presigned Url > 5gb limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, limit, pre-signed-url

I have scoured the web for more information on the upload limit of AWS S3 presigned urls, but have not found a clear answer.

I have seen that by default AWS will limit the file size to 5gb, but you do have the ability to add a content length header defining a different size.

My question is:
Can you define a content-length for the presigned url that is larger than 5gb and thereby upload a file larger than the default 5gb or would we have to look into multipart uploads and splitting the file?

Multipart uploads does have other benefits, but it will be a larger task that just adding a custom content-length.

Thx in advance

Comment: Single part uploads are [limited to 5gb](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/).  Larger uploads must use multipart uploads.

Comment: you can use presigned multipart upload